# Traffic not passing through the site-to-site VPN Sonicwall (VM on Azure) to Sonicwall on premises

Tags: networking, vpn, azure, site-to-site-vpn, sonicwall

I have created a VPN site-to-site with a Sonicwall NSv on Azure and a TZ400 on-premises. The VPN is ON but the traffic between the two sites does not go through. I am able to ping the X0 (LAN interface) on NSv from the site but not the other VMs sitting behind the Sonicwall. I have created the routing table on vnet on Azure to route all the traffic to the X0 LAN interface of the Sonicwall (it works). The other site-to-site VPNs that I have between the physical firewalls on the other sites work perfectly fine, but not with the NSv model on Azure.

Sonicwall support was useless. Am I missing something?

[image: Diagram]

Comment: Did you create rules to allow access on Azure for the VM Subnet?

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the answer. 

After a log period of troubleshooting if found a resolution. 
first, I had to move all the VMs to another subnet within the same vNet. After that, i create a routing table to route all the traffic from the new subnet to the Sonicwall LAN port X0. then create a static route from SonicWall to that subnet using X0 and the last step was to create another Azure routing table from the on-prem local network to the Sonicwall Lan Port X0. 
now everything is working